# Not able to take pictures with CameraKit in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera

I'm trying to use CameraKit in order to take a picture. So far, I've been able to implement CameraKit and get a preview stream from my camera.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.testapp
import com.camerakit.CameraKitView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_camera_screen.*


class cameraScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var cameraKitView:CameraKitView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_screen)
        cameraKitView = findViewById(R.id.camera)

        photoButton.setOnClickListener{
            cameraKitView.captureImage(object:CameraKitView.ImageCallback() {
                 override fun onImage(cameraKitView:CameraKitView, capturedImage:ByteArray) {
                    // capturedImage contains the image from the CameraKitView.
                     Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Image Taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 }
            })
        }

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        cameraKitView.onStart()

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        cameraKitView.onResume()

    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        cameraKitView.onPause()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        cameraKitView.onStop()
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        cameraKitView.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
}
```

Now according to the CameraKit Docs, this is what makes an image:

```
cameraKitView.captureImage(new  CameraKitView.ImageCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onImage(CameraKitView cameraKitView, final byte[] capturedImage) {
        // capturedImage contains the image from the CameraKitView.
    }
})
```

As you can see, I've tried to convert this Java code into Kotlin above. However, on this line - `cameraKitView.captureImage(object:CameraKitView.ImageCallback() {` I keep getting an error

> This class does not have a constructor

I am getting this error on ImageCallback(). I've tried numerous examples about how to capture an image from CameraKit but all of them are in Java and when I convert them, they all give me the same error.

How do I resolve this?
Additionally, how do I preview the image once it's taken, until the user taps a button to save it ( or reject it, in which case I go back to the camera)?

## Update

Removed the round braces from  the`cameraKitView.captureImage(object:CameraKitView.ImageCallback()` line. This made the error go away and showed the toast as well but there is no response from the app so I don't really know if the picture is being taken or not.

The new line now is `cameraKitView.captureImage(object:CameraKitView.ImageCallback`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use

```
cameraKitView.captureImage(object:CameraKitView.ImageCallback()
```

in fact because I don't know how to use it either.

If possible, try the following method to get the captured image. It returns images bytearray style, and you can use it to do what you want!

```
btnLaunchCameraKit.setOnClickListener {
    cameraKitView.captureImage { cameraKitView, bytes ->
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.size) as Bitmap
        cameraImage3.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I, however, abandoned the project so I can't tell if it's correct or not.